# Alamofire post request with json encoding

Tags: swift, alamofire

How to send a post request with Alamofire with parameters as json having list of integers i.e, my server expects a dictionary whose value for the key is a list of integers.

I want the parameters as {"abc":[1,2,3]}. How to send this along post request of Alamofire in swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire: Sending JSON as request parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793155/alamofire-sending-json-as-request-parameter)

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#json-encoding

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
 var parameter  = ["abc": [1,2,3]]
 Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://www.yoursite.com/api" , parameters:parameter)
```

I would also look at the documentation over at [Alamofire github documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) which is really helpful.

Comment: yes I did. Just to debug i am sending back the request.data as a response from the server which gives me like  { "abc[]" = 3;}

Comment: So do you want to return the same parameter as dictionary from the server? If that is the case, this sounds like a server side issue.

Comment: In my server it checks for a keyword named "abc" in request.data. It doesn't get this keyword.

Comment: request.data should be like {"abc": [1,2,3]}

Comment: Their documentation is horrible. Where can I use the advertised `ParameterEncoding`

Comment: @FullDecent You can use the parameter encoding like this:   Almofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)         This is for encoding it to json. You can use as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

an other solution from official documentation.

```
let parameters = [
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": ["a", 1],
    "qux": [
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 3
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters)
// HTTP body: foo=bar&baz[]=a&baz[]=1&qux[x]=1&qux[y]=2&qux[z]=3
```

I dont understand how to check your data at the backend on your server but I guess you can check your **abc** data result like a string **[1,2,3]**

```
let parameters = [
    "abc": "[1,2,3]"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Your answer does not use json encoding

Answer (score 0):

```
let parameters = [
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": ["a", 1],
    "qux": [
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 3
    ]
]

    Alamofire.request(url,method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON{
                (response) in
                print(response, parameters)
            }
```

This should work