# How to create a dictionary with 2 arrays inside?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I want to create a dictionary with the next structure, for sending it via Alamofire as JSON to a server:

```
{
    "user": {
        "firstName": "fName",
         "lastName": null,
         "img": null,
         "books": [
             {
                 "id": 1
             }, {
                 "id": 2
             }
         ]
    },

    "locale": "en",
    "gender": "male"
}
```

For this structure of JSON, I've tried the next:

```
let parameters: [[String: [String: String]], [String: String]]
```

but there a lot closures, so I confused with it. Can you help me with creating this structure?

Comment: I think it looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793155/alamofire-sending-json-as-request-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection types in the Swift standard library only support homogenous collections, i.e. all elements in a collection must have the same type. So you cannot declare an array whose first element is of type `[String: [String: String]]` and whose second element is of type `[String: String]` if that is what you wanted.

This works:

```
let parameters = [
    "user": [
        "firstName": "fName",
        "lastName": NSNull(),
        "img": NSNull(),
        "books": [
            [ "id": 1],
            [ "id": 2]
        ]
    ],
    "locale": "en",
    "gender": "male"
]
```

The type of `parameters` is `[String: NSObject]` where `NSObject` is the superclass of all the values in the dictionary. Note the use of `NSNull` to model `null` values, which is what `NSJSONSerialization` expects.

Comment: Alamofire requires `AnyObject`, there's no need to force `NSObject`.

Comment: True, but the type inferred by the compiler is `[String: NSObject]`.

Comment: it prints my `NSNull()` as `email = "<null>";` is it okay? It's like a string here